# text won't display in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a mobile layout for a css project. I want the header and the footer to stay fixed on the screen so that I can scroll through the rest of the content in between them. That turned out to be a success, except that none of my text will display.

```css
body {
  width: 21em;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header,
.footer {
  z-index: 2;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='content'>
  <p>
    Despite the traumatic environment that typified his youth, he always knew his mother loved him deeply and always tried to protect him. To this wonderful woman, family meant everything and that unshaken commitment found a safe place within her young son’s
    soul. And, even though this humble new member had already endured such great danger and fear at an early age, his newly discovered faith immediately became a way of life which he now unhesitatingly shares with everyone he meets. He further affirmed
    that accepting the message taught by missionaries that helped him re-find his faith, repent, be baptized, and receive the gift of the Holy Ghost was the easiest “hard” thing he has ever done. For added emphasis, he reminded us that following Christ
    is not complicated so we just need
  </p>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Comment: If you do not want to changes any of your applied style then add `top: 0;` to `.header` and `top:30%;`(same as the height of header always) to `.content`.
Else try to find how to do this with a phantom element. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `margin-top` to the body so that the `content` will be moved, and add `top: 0;` to the header so that it is always in the topmost part

Just adjust the margin to fit your needs

```css
body {
  width: 21em;
  margin-top:20%;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header,
.footer {
  z-index: 2;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='content'>
  <p>
    Despite the traumatic environment that typified his youth, he always knew his mother loved him deeply and always tried to protect him. To this wonderful woman, family meant everything and that unshaken commitment found a safe place within her young son’s
    soul. And, even though this humble new member had already endured such great danger and fear at an early age, his newly discovered faith immediately became a way of life which he now unhesitatingly shares with everyone he meets. He further affirmed
    that accepting the message taught by missionaries that helped him re-find his faith, repent, be baptized, and receive the gift of the Holy Ghost was the easiest “hard” thing he has ever done. For added emphasis, he reminded us that following Christ
    is not complicated so we just need
  </p>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Comment: This answer is dependent on page height - inline here there's a huge white space, and with full page I lose the first line.

Comment: Well OP used percent as unit, so I also used it. But this shows how to make the content not overlapped by the fixed header